# SVM model prediction inquiry

Tags: r, svm

I am new to R, and made simple SVM model for classification of a document.

```
library(tm)
library(e1071) 

# my sample data
texts <-c("soccer",
          "games",
          "basketball",
          "games games games games")    

categories <- c("sports","e-sports", "sports", "e-sports")

# my sample dtm
dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(Corpus(VectorSource(texts)))

df <- data.frame(categories, as.data.frame(inspect(dtm)))

# model based on sample data
model <- svm(categories~., data=df)

# new data to be classified 
new <- c("soccer basketball games games games games")

dtm_n <- DocumentTermMatrix(Corpus(VectorSource(new)) )

inspect(dtm_n)

df_n <- as.data.frame(inspect(dtm_n))

# doing the prediction
predict(model, df_n)
```

Let's say I have made this simple svm model, and use this model to predict another random document. If I run that, I get

```
df_n <- as.data.frame(inspect(dtm_n))
<<DocumentTermMatrix (documents: 1, terms: 3)>>
Non-/sparse entries: 3/0
Sparsity           : 0%
Maximal term length: 10
Weighting          : term frequency (tf)
Sample             :
    Terms
Docs basketball games soccer
   1          1     4      1
> 
> predict(model, df_n)
     1 
sports 
Levels: e-sports sports
```

Not sure how it ends up with this result.

According to wikepedia, svm works like
given a set of training examples, each marked as belonging to one or the other of two categories, an SVM training algorithm builds a model that assigns new examples to one category or the other.

Then, in my case, how can I build a training algorithm?
Is there a good place to see how the model is actually set up and processed in R? Or would you give me a brief explanation about the svm/prediction process?

If someone can help me to be on the right track, please give me a suggestion.

Thank you for reading this, and hope you have a great day.